# How to custom format date in jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need in jQuery/Javascript to display a date (comming from a DatePicker) with more information and depending on language:

The Date I get from the DatePicker displays as : **17-06-2022**

```
I need it to display as (In Danish)  : Fredag d. 17 Juni 2022
                        (In English) : Friday 17th June 2022
```

**My code:**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#BtnProceed').click(function() {
        var date = document.getElementById("ConfirmEndDateHolder").value = EndCalendar.getFormatedDate();
        $("#ConfirmEndDateHolder").text(date);
  });    
});
```

Can someone help me achive this?

Comment: You would need to manually build date strings in those formats. There are libraries which can help you with this, such as [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/), although you would need to build the logic to differentiate the user's language/culture yourself.

Comment: [.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)  eg `date.toLocaleString('da-DK', {weekday: 'long'});`

Comment: There are also lots of [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+detect+user+language) on how to detect user's language.

Comment: Thanks Guys .. I think I might need to look into the moment.js then .. I am not able to get `$("#ConfirmEndDateHolder").text(date.toLocaleString('da-DK', {weekday: 'long'}));` to display other than i.e. 17-06-2022 .. maybe I am doing something wrong?